# Only display on sidebar if only got value inserted on post

Tags: sidebar

**This is the statement of post submit:***

```
<fieldset>        
  <label for=MarketItem_cost><?php echo __('Software Version', 'WpForest'); ?>:</label>
  <p><input type="text" size="50" class="do_input"  name="soft" value="<?php echo get_post_meta( $pid, 'WpForest_soft', true ); ?>" /> 
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

**This is the statement on sidebar display:**

```
<tr>
  <td class="attr-name"><?php echo __('Software Version', 'WpForest'); ?></td>
  <td class="attr-detail"><?php if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'WpForest_soft', true )) : ?> </td>
</tr>
```

What I want is that, if any value is input on post form, then it will appear on the sidebar but when input is blank it will not show.

Right now it will show everything on sidebar, where there is value on input given or not.

How to code it with my present coding stated above.

Comment: It's impossible read you question. Can you edit it please?

Comment: I would say this: `if(false !== get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'WpForest_soft', true ))` but I'm not quite sure of what you want exactly.

Comment: How can someone input if the field isn't there? Your question presents a paradox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
// Get the 'WpForest_soft' custom field value.
$text = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'WpForest_soft', true );

// Print the value and surrounding markup only if the value tests true.
if ( $text )
    printf( '<tr><td class="attr-name">%s</td><td class="attr-detail">%s</td></tr>', __( 'Software Version', 'WpForest' ), $text );
```

General Case

To do the above with any optional markup follow these steps.

1) Place the custom field value of in a variable. Use a relevant variable name.

```
// Get the 'WpForest_soft' custom field value.
$wpforest_soft = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'WpForest_soft', true );
```

2) Write a PHP conditional testing the value from step 1.

```
if ( $wpforest_soft ) {
}
```

3) Add your markup to that conditonal.

```
if ( $wpforest_soft ) {
    ?>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/theme-demo/<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" class='blue-btn right ml10 live-preview' target='_blank'>Live Preview</a>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/theme-demo/<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" class='blue-btn right ml10 live-preview' target='_blank'>Video Preview</a>
    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/screenshots/<?php echo the_ID(); ?>" class='blue-btn right ml10 screenshots' target='_blank'>Screenshots</a>
    <?php
}
```

4) (Optional) Avoid jumping in and out of PHP and Markup. The [printf()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.printf.php) PHP function can help.

```
if ( $wpforest_soft ) {
    printf(
        '<a href="%1$s/theme-demo/%2$s" class="%3$s" target="_blank">Live Preview</a>' .
        '<a href="%1$s/theme-demo/%2$s" class="%3$s" target="_blank">Video Preview</a>' .
        '<a href="%1$s/screenshots/%2$s" class="%4$s" target="_blank">Screenshots</a>',

        get_bloginfo( 'url' ),
        get_the_ID(),
        'blue-btn right ml10 live-preview',
        'blue-btn right ml10 screenshots'
    );
}
```

Or just:

```
if ( $wpforest_soft )

    printf(
        '<a href="%1$s/theme-demo/%2$s" class="%3$s" target="_blank">Live Preview</a>' .
        '<a href="%1$s/theme-demo/%2$s" class="%3$s" target="_blank">Video Preview</a>' .
        '<a href="%1$s/screenshots/%2$s" class="%4$s" target="_blank">Screenshots</a>',

        get_bloginfo( 'url' ),
        get_the_ID(),
        'blue-btn right ml10 live-preview',
        'blue-btn right ml10 screenshots'
    );
```

Comment: "This answer was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Please try to explain what your code does in human readable terms.

Comment: Hai Charles Clarkson i need one more help,i want to do the same for video preview,screenshots and live preview but it come with button.How to code using my statement below.

Comment: <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/theme-demo/<?php echo the_ID(); ?>"  class='blue-btn right ml10 live-preview' target='_blank'>Live Preview</a><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/theme-demo/<?php echo the_ID(); ?>"  class='blue-btn right ml10 live-preview' target='_blank'>Video Preview</a><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/screenshots/<?php echo the_ID(); ?>"  class='blue-btn right ml10 screenshots' target='_blank'>Screenshots</a>

Comment: @mus720714 See edit.

Comment: Thank you very  much for your help Charles Clarkson,everythings seems to be working perfectly,thanks again.

Comment: @mus720714, If this answer is acceptable, please mark the question as answered. And you're welcome.

Comment: Charles i again need your help,starting with this,i got a value of two prices, i want is similar like the above. 
my code:
foreach($res as $row){
  if (!empty($row->pid)) {
  $post_id = get_post($row->pid);
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th><a href="'.get_permalink($post_id->ID).'">'.$post_id->post_title .'</a></th>';
echo '<th>'.wpforest_currency_simb().get_post_meta( $post_id->ID, 'WpForest_price', true ).' '.  

:-what i want to make on and off for the (WpForest_price) mean normal price (WpForest_price 1) mean extended price.How to code it with my statement above thanks.

Comment: @mus720714, There should be a checkmark under the down arrow near the top of the answer below the zero (0).

Comment: Start a new question for the code (starting with `foreach`) above and then refer back to this page, if it is related. You can ask a lot of questions each month. You are no limited to just one and it is easier for us to answer them like that. HTH, Charles.